# How can I display posts in wordpress based on page category?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I would like to know how I can display single posts for a specific page.

ex. page url
http://www.yourblog.com/services/single-service-post-title

I tried creating "single-service.php" but it redirects me to my static front page.

I have setup a page-services.php and that one works fine, but that page is designed to only show a summary of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, since pages can't have single posts. They're two different things.

If you're looking for a way to create a template for a single custom post type, you can view an [interactive version of the hierarchy here](http://wphierarchy.com/).

You have to name the file based on the id of the custom post type. So if the id of the post type is 'service', then 'single-service.php' would display the single post where post type equals service.

You can also place logic into your 'single.php' to say something like

```
if(get_post_type(get_the_ID()) == 'service'){
    // DO SERVICE-SPECIFIC STUFF HERE
}
```

This is usually for single custom post types that don't have their own template, but it can also be used as a fallback if that's something you're worried about.

Then you can use an `else` for regular post stuff and put stuff common to both outside of the `if/else`.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up for me, but to be sure if I want to do that i create a custom post type and than the single-(posttype) loads the template ?

Comment: Yes, it should. Every custom theme is different, so something might interfere with it, but generally, yes. If you have the custom post type, create a php template called `single-posttype.php` and it should use that file for displaying a single post in that post type.